# How to compress objects into strings without losing too much information

Tags: java, compression, text-files, lossless-compression

Trying to figure out how to make a class that can create objects based on text files. If the interface Readable has the method String asString(), and the method Readable read(String s) in a class is to construct a Readable object based on the string s, so that (read(String s).asString()).equals(s), I've been able to easily write read using reflection if the Readable type being written/read has only primitive arguments, but I'm not sure how to write them to easily convert to and from a string when the constructor takes an arbitrary amount of Readable classes in an arbitrary order. For using only primitives, the asString method reads as follows:

```
private int n, double d;
...
public String asString(){
    return "@"+getClass().getName()+"#i%d#"+this.n+"%"+this.d;
}
```

The symbols are arbitrary characters allowing me to use String.split, and i and d give the primitive types of the fields n and d, since Class.forName doesn't work with primitives. This problem requires me to have around 7 layers of nested Readables, however, some of which have containers of arbitrary amounts of Readables. I understand how to write the read method based on the string, but how do I compress an object into a string while retaining all of the necessary information?

Comment: Look into [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [ObjectInputSteam](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)

Comment: Why don't you use `XMLEncoder`/`XMLDecoder` in the standard library?

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of either of these.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the Java API: `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.

Your class needs to implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface to be written to a stream/created from a stream.

### Example:

```
public class WriteMe implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1234567890L; // Should be generated

    private int myInt = 164;
    private Date myDate = new Date();
    private transient int money = 1648; // Will be ignored
}
```

### In your main class:

```
public class HelloStackoverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(System.out); // Print to standard output
        os.writeObject(new WriteMe());
    }
}
```

***You can do the same with ObjectInputStream and .readObject().***

If you want to store your object as a `String`, you should encode it using Base64, because the output will be Java-Bytecode!

Answer (score 0):

As Titus already said - why inventing the wheel again. 
With ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream java already already have such mechanism